# Noun for a "dual side product"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to express a concept about source code.

Coding style of the code is like a product for developer, especially on open sourced product. If the style is well established and maintained, developers consider it a good product and vice versa.

But the code is a product for the machine, too. So no matter the coding style, as long as the logic is correct, the result of execution is the same.

How can I express a kind of product that is good in both respects, in one special word?

Comment: Two sided is "bilateral." Something that acts both ways is "twofold." Your code could be "a double-edged sword," that cuts both ways, is equally good in both respects.